# Origen interactive mode - using basic linux grep/find

Tags: origen-sdk

Is there a way to add/concatenate/pipe a grep command when searching for registers in the origen interactive mode.

eg. If i want to look at registers say, I do
**> dut.mainregs**
and it returns 100 registers.
Is there a way to do something like
**>dut.mainregs('grep regname')** or **>dut.mainregs | grep regname**, etc?

Or is there any other way to search for some string?

Answer (score 0):

At the very end of this [doc](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/registers/) you will see an example:

```
# Iterate over all registers matching a regular expression
# Ex 1: Only ADC cfg registers (:adc0_cfg, :adc1_cfg)
dut.regs('/acd\d_cfg/').each do |r|
  # do something with register r
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I did have issues using the \d. Is that some form of escape sequence before special characters?

Comment: \d just means a single numeric character.  If need one or more use \d+.